# log(n) "sort by value" Map<K, V>?

Tags: java, sorting, hash-map

I've read so much [arguing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) about "sort by value maps". Well, I wrote the following log(n) sort by value *Map* . And, by the way, a real *Map* , does not allow duplicate keys. Many of the maps I googled ignore that annoying problem. I assume this map is still log(n)...:

```
public static void sortByValue_logN() {

    class MyComp implements Comparator {
        Map<Object, Integer> sharedMap;

        public int compare(Object key1, Object key2) {
            if(key1.equals(key2)) { return 0; }

            Integer val1 = sharedMap.get(key1);
            Integer val2 = sharedMap.get(key2);

            if(val1 > val2) return -1; 
            return 1;
        }     

    }

    class TreeMapByValue<K> extends TreeMap<K, Integer> {
        Map<Object, Integer> sharedMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
        TreeMapByValue(Comparator comp) {
            super(comp);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer put(K key, Integer val) {
            if(sharedMap.containsKey(key)) {
                super.remove(key);
                val += sharedMap.get(key);
            }
            sharedMap.put(key, val);

            super.put(key, val);

            return val;
        }
    }

    MyComp myComp = new MyComp();
    TreeMapByValue<Object> myMap = new TreeMapByValue(myComp);
    myComp.sharedMap = myMap.sharedMap;


    // all the rest is just testing the map
    Random rand = new Random();
    String[] story = { "The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped" };

    for(int repeat = 0; repeat < 3; repeat++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < story.length; i++) {
            String key = story[i];
            int value = rand.nextInt(100);
            myMap.put(key, value);
            System.out.println(key + "-->" + value);
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<Object, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("key = " + entry.getKey() + "___value = " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Surely (at least stylistically) something is bad about the above code.

I don't understand generics yet, so I am ok with ignoring that for now. I am also ignoring thread-safety issues as well.

My goal is to create a log(n) "sort by value" map that respects the property of not having duplicate keys. So, what is wrong with what I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`put` seems quite broken, which in turn breaks `get`.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html),

> `V put(K key, V value)`
>
> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map
>   (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for
>   the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value. (A map `m` is
>   said to contain a mapping for a key `k` if and only if `m.containsKey(k)`
>   would return `true`.)
>
> Returns:
>   the previous value associated with `key`, or `null` if there was no mapping for `key`. (A `null` return can also indicate that the map previously associated `null` with key, if the implementation supports null values.)

Let's take this code

```
  myMap.put("x", 1);
  int oldValue = myMap.put("x", 2);
  System.out.printf("%d %d%n", oldValue, myMap.get("x"));
```

I would expect it to print `1 2`, but it prints `3 3`.

Comment: Yes. I understand your point. I do need to make it conform to the api. I've never really done programming before. thanks.

Comment: Actually, I just realized a catastrophic failure? What I did breaks the "is a" relationship with TreeMap. I can't let anyone get a reference to an instance of "TreeMapByValue" because via reflection they can see the "is a" relationship with TreeMap (which TreeMapByValue is not). I know what to do. And, as a side-effect, now I don't need to worry about complying to the TreeMap API that you mentioned. got it.